# Implementing Parcelable for Date Object - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I am trying to pull the release date value from TheMovieDatabase API. One of the items it returns is a `Date` value.

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeInt(vote_count);
    parcel.writeInt(id);
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (video ? 1:0));
    parcel.writeString(title);
    parcel.writeFloat(popularity);
    parcel.writeString(poster_path);
    parcel.writeString(original_language);
    parcel.writeString(original_title);
    parcel.writeStringList(genre_ids);
    parcel.writeString(backdrop_path);
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (adult ? 1:0));
    parcel.writeString(overview);
    parcel.writeLong(release_date.getTime());


}
```

IndividualMovieActivity.java:

```
public class IndividualMovieActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mMovieTitle;
private ImageView mMoviePoster;
private TextView mMovieReleaseDate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_individual_movie);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Movie movie = intent.getParcelableExtra("Movie");
    String title = movie.getOriginal_title();
    Log.v("POSTER_PATH", movie.getPoster_path());
    Log.v("RELEASE", movie.getRelease_date().toString());

    mMovieTitle = findViewById(R.id.movie_name);
    mMoviePoster = findViewById(R.id.movie_details_movie_poster_image);
    mMovieReleaseDate = findViewById(R.id.movie_details_release_date);

    mMovieTitle.setText(title);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + movie.getPoster_path())
            .into(mMoviePoster);

    mMovieReleaseDate.setText((CharSequence) movie.getRelease_date());

   }
}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String java.util.Date.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>               at popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies.IndividualMovieActivity.onCreate(IndividualMovieActivity.java:29)

Full Source Code:
https://github.com/troy21688/PopularMovies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project's linked source code, these are the parcelable "read" and "write" methods:

> ```
> protected Movie(Parcel in) {
>     vote_count = in.readInt();
>     id = in.readInt();
>     video = in.readByte() != 0;
>     title = in.readString();
>     popularity = in.readFloat();
>     poster_path = in.readString();
>     original_language = in.readString();
>     original_title = in.readString();
>     genre_ids = in.createStringArrayList();
>     backdrop_path = in.readString();
>     adult = in.readByte() != 0;
>     overview = in.readString();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
>     parcel.writeInt(vote_count);
>     parcel.writeInt(id);
>     parcel.writeByte((byte) (video ? 1:0));
>     parcel.writeString(title);
>     parcel.writeFloat(popularity);
>     parcel.writeString(poster_path);
>     parcel.writeString(original_language);
>     parcel.writeString(original_title);
>     parcel.writeStringList(genre_ids);
>     parcel.writeString(backdrop_path);
>     parcel.writeByte((byte) (adult ? 1:0));
>     parcel.writeString(overview);
>     parcel.writeLong(release_date.getTime());
> }
> ```

If you look carefully, you'll see that the Parcel constructor doesn't have a "read" operation for `release_date`. You probably need to add something like this:

```
release_date = new Date(in.readLong());
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/troy21688/PopularMovies/blob/master/app/src/main/java/popularmovies/troychuinard/com/popularmovies/Model/Movie.java), it doesn't look like the `Movie(Parcel in)`  constructor ever initializes `this.release_date`, so it is null when you try to access it.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a similar app called [Cinemate](https://github.com/Jantzilla/Cinemate) using "TheMovieDatabase API" as a project, part of Udacity's Android Nanodegree program.

It appears to me, you may have a type problem. Try retrieving the date from the endpoint as a `String` and modify your `Movie` class accordingly.